# run Javascript when tab is focused

Tags: javascript

Is there any `javascript library` to detect whether the tab is in focus or not and then execute the code accordingly?

Comment: I think you can do it with native JS, something like `window.onfocus = function() {
console.log('focussed');
}`

Comment: For sure there is a jQuery library for this.

Answer (score 4):

By this code you can check whether the window is in focus or not:

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    document.title = 'focused';
});

window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    document.title = 'not focused';
});
```

And other thing, you have to code it up yourself if you face problems ask a question and add the code you tried along with it

**Update:** There is a little problem with this and also with the other answer given, the problem is that just scrolling won't make it work. You will need to interact with the page to make it work. But the accepted answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active) might work for scrolling too

Answer (score 2):

You can possible do this with native JS code like:

```
window.onfocus = function() {
    console.log('focussed');
}

window.onblur = function() {
    console.log('blurred');
}
```